# LibGDX / Java weird behaviour

Tags: java, libgdx

This is a game being made in LibGDX. The user can spawn sheep, which then are supposed to wander around randomly. There are two problems.

1. The sheep do not always change their "right" variable.
2. They seem to always move in the same way, which should not be happening.

Here's the code for the MainClass and Entity classes. The others shouldn't be the causes of this bug.

Main:

```
package com.god.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MainClass extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public static final int width = 1600;
    public static final int height = 1000;
    public static final String title = "God Game";

    public static EntityType[] entityTypes;
    public static float rand, cameraSpeed;
    public static Comparator<Entity> layerComp;
    public static int selectedId;
    public static String aiStr;
    public static InputMultiplexer input;

    SpriteBatch batch;

    public static ArrayList<Entity> entities;
    public static OrthographicCamera camera;
    public static Vector3 mousePos;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        input = new InputMultiplexer();
        input.addProcessor(new com.god.game.Input());
        input.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(new Gestures()));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input);

        entityTypes = new EntityType[]{new EntityType("Sheep", new Vector2(55, 38), new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Textures/sheep.atlas")), 20, new AI(new String[]{"Wander"}))};
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

        layerComp = new Comparator<Entity>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
                if (e1.getPosition().y > e2.getPosition().y)
                    return -1;
                if (e1.getPosition().y < e2.getPosition().y)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }
        };

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
        cameraSpeed = 500;
        selectedId = 0;

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime){

        handleInput(deltaTime);

        for(Entity e : entities){
            e.update(deltaTime);
        }

        Collections.sort(entities, layerComp);

        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0.8f, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        for(Entity e : entities){
            if(!e.isRight())
                entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()).flip(true, false);
            batch.draw(entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()), e.getPosition().x, e.getPosition().y);
            if(!e.isRight())
                entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()).flip(true, false);
        }
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        batch.dispose();
        for(EntityType e : entityTypes)
            e.dispose();
    }

    public void handleInput(float deltaTime){

        mousePos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(mousePos);

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
            camera.translate(0, cameraSpeed*deltaTime);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
            camera.translate(-cameraSpeed*deltaTime, 0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
            camera.translate(0, -cameraSpeed*deltaTime);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
            camera.translate(cameraSpeed*deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.god.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Entity {
    private int id;
    private Vector2 position, goalPos;
    private boolean right;
    private String frame;
    private float animationTimer;

    public Entity(int id, Vector2 position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;
        this.right = true;
        this.frame = "stand";
        this.animationTimer = 0;
        this.goalPos = Vector2.Zero;
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime){
        MainClass.aiStr = MainClass.entityTypes[id].getAi().getBrainList()[0];
        if(MainClass.aiStr == "Wander"){
            MainClass.rand = MathUtils.random(1000);

            if(MainClass.rand == 1){
                goalPos.x = -1;
                right = false;
            }
            else if(MainClass.rand == 2)
                goalPos.x = 0;
            else if(MainClass.rand == 3){
                goalPos.x = 1;
                right = true;
            }

            MainClass.rand = MathUtils.random(1000);

            if(MainClass.rand == 1)
                goalPos.y = -1;
            else if(MainClass.rand == 2)
                goalPos.y = 0;
            else if(MainClass.rand == 3)
                goalPos.y = 1;

            moveForward(deltaTime);
        }
        else{
            frame = "stand";
            animationTimer = 0;
        }
        animationTimer += deltaTime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public boolean isRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(boolean right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void setFrame(String frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public float getAnimationTimer() {
        return animationTimer;
    }

    public void setAnimationTimer(float animationTimer) {
        this.animationTimer = animationTimer;
    }

    public Vector2 getGoalPos() {
        return goalPos;
    }

    public void setGoalPos(Vector2 goalPos) {
        this.goalPos = goalPos;
    }

    public void moveForward(float deltaTime){
        position.x += MainClass.entityTypes[id].getMoveSpeed() * deltaTime * goalPos.x;
        position.y += MainClass.entityTypes[id].getMoveSpeed() * deltaTime * goalPos.y;
        if(goalPos.x == 0 && goalPos.y == 0){
            frame = "stand";
            animationTimer = 0;
        }
        else if(animationTimer >= 0.2f){
            if(frame.equals("stand"))
                frame = "move";
            else
                frame = "stand";
            animationTimer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The sheep SHOULD all be setting their right variables to true/false every time they change their goalPos.x to -1 or 1, but they don't seem to do so. They also don't seem to move independently, instead they're like a formation, moving in the same direction each time. They do independently set their right variables to true/false, but it doesn't match their movement. Ex: A sheep is moving right, and then randomly turns left while still moving right, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should never say Java is behaving weird but rather that you code is not behaving as you expected. If you blame some inner java functionality for your bugs you won't ever find them. Now let's take a look what happens if your ai is set to `wander`.

```
if(MainClass.aiStr == "Wander"){
        MainClass.rand = MathUtils.random(1000);
//Random number in the range of 0 to 1000.

        if(MainClass.rand == 1){ //happens .1% of the time
            goalPos.x = -1;
            right = false;
        }
        else if(MainClass.rand == 2) //happens .1% of the time
            goalPos.x = 0;
        else if(MainClass.rand == 3){ //happens .1% of the time
            goalPos.x = 1;
            right = true;
        }
 //since there is no else nothing happens 99.7% of the time.
    }
```

My guess is that your code is behaving as you should expect and there is no black voodoo going on inside your computer. So in the future blame yourself and inspect your code, it's really not that much code and only a tiny part of what you posted is responsible for steering your entities.

Now what you probably want is something like this `MathUtils.random(1, 4)` since maximum is exclusive. Or `MathUtils.random(1, 5)` if you want 25% of the time nothing to happen.

A more scalable way in terms of chance I always prefer something like this:

```
int randomNumber = MathUtils.random(1, 101);
if (randomNumber <= 33)
{
  //do something 33% of the time
}
else if (randomNumber <= 66)
{
  //do something 33% of the time
}
else
{
  //do something 34% of the time
}
```

Now this is easier to alter since all you need to do is change the percentages and you can easily add another case.

```
if (randomNumber <= 20)
{
  //do something 20% of the time
}
else if (randomNumber <= 60)
{
  //do something 40% of the time
}
else if (randomNumber <= 58)
{
  //do something 18% of the time
}
else
{
  //do something 22% of the time
}
```

Comment: I didn't necessarily state it was Java's/LibGDX's fault, just that it seemed weird because It made no sense, but I'm sorry if you took it that way. Also, the reason MathUtils.random is all the way to 1000 is so that the sheep can walk forward for a few seconds (because their goalPos doesn't change) and then change their direction, instead of just going slightly left and right, which doesn't look like wandering. But even setting it from 1 to 4 wouldn't solve the problem, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Well let us say your word choice is unfortunate then. If possible try to just ask the question without any other noise here on SO. Since you are pretty sure you might want to check to make sure, least you can do if someone puts effort in helping you. I understand what you mean, right now rand should be 1 each 16 seconds if you run at 60fps.16 seconds is rather long and if your "unlucky" this can easily be minutes. You might also want to make `MainClass.rand` a int. You are putting a int in it anyway and you are comparing vs int as well so there is no reason to have it as a float.

Comment: Do the statements get ever even triggered? You tried debugging it? I tested your randomizer and they all get triggered, sometimes it takes a bit long though. If you want something to idle or walk straight just use my method or even set a timer with a random value to skip the statements all together.

Comment: They get triggered, but for some reason the sheep all seem to always have the same goalPos, and they set their boolean right to true even when going left, and vice-versa.

Here's the jar if you want to see it for yourself.
https://www.mediafire.com/?orad0hjdkqseylr

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are acessing variables on static way, like

```
         [...]
    MainClass.aiStr = MainClass.entityTypes[id].getAi().getBrainList()[0];
         [...]
    MainClass.rand = MathUtils.random(1000);
         [...]
```

so all the sheeps are gonna use this same value and move like the same, just make those calls on the same instance.

If you are math rand 1000 and comparing if the value is 1 its 0,1% chance per frame, if your game is locked on 30fps the chances for it to trigger is very, very low.

You are checking twice   **if(!e.isRight())** on the render method, so it will flip twice.

```
 for(Entity e : entities){
            if(!e.isRight())
                entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()).flip(true, false);
            batch.draw(entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()), e.getPosition().x, e.getPosition().y);
            if(!e.isRight())
                entityTypes[e.getId()].getAtlas().findRegion(e.getFrame()).flip(true, false);
        }
```

Could you provide more info about EntityType class? So we can find out what are you doing when you're setting the movingspeed on the entity.

[Edit] as stated by mbrlabs always uses .equals to compare strings, because even they look the same they actually are 2 different objects on the memory containing the same text, so using == will never be true.

Comment: Here you can see every class:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21900
Here is the executable .jar file:
https://www.mediafire.com/?orad0hjdkqseylr

The MainClass.rand gets changed every time before it is used, so they don't use the same numbers. I tried making everything not static, it had the same effect. Static doesn't cause the problem. It isn't locked at 30, and even if it was it wouldn't matter. When it gets the right number it changes direction. With a lower chance, it actually walks forward some time before turning around. It flips twice to reset the texture.

Answer (score 0):

In your Entity class change this `if(MainClass.aiStr == "Wander")` to `MainClass.aiStr.equals("Wander")`.

When you compare strings, you should always do it this way. By using == you are comparing the reference, but you want to compare the actual content of the string. 
The code between the if statement is most likely never executed, because you are comparing references.

Comment: I changed it, but it still behaves the same.